# Which type of harmonica is the best suit for country music?

Tags: blues, harmonica

I want to play harmonica but I am not sure which type of harmonica is the correct choice for country music ? Everyone talks about blues but is same type of harmonica fits for both blues and country ?

Comment: This book taught me harmonica very effectively: https://gindick.com/product/country-blues-harmonica-for-the-musically-hopeless-hopeful/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really are only two types of harmonicas: chromatic and diatonic. Chromatic harmonicas have a button that allows you to switch around airflow, getting you all twelve notes. Diatonic harmonicas do not, but by bending notes, you can get all 12 notes on a diatonic harmonica. They are available in many keys. I don't know if it's all twelve, but I know there are high-C and low-C harps.

Some makers, like Hohner, tune the harmonicas so that they work for chords, as they originally were meant, while others like Lee Oskar are tuned for melodic playing.

But (generally) the Country style is straight harp (playing the major scale; C on a C harmonica) with little bending, while Blues involves cross harp (G on a C harmonica, Mixolydian with bends to get the blue notes). Both of these styles use diatonic harmonica.

Comment: A couple notes: a “blues harp” is diatonic, so it is suitable for country music. And while chromatic and diatonic are the two main types, the asker could also run into “tremolo”, “octave”, and “orchestra” types, and should avoid those as a beginner.

Comment: "Both these styles use diatonic harmonica", so yeah. And "(generally)", because Blues techniques are not unknown in Country. But yes, absolutely, there are other types, more than I mentioned or even knew, but if you go to a music store and ask for a harmonica, they'll likely show you diatonics.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer sir. I got Hohner Special 20. I could not wait for answers though cuz I was so ambitions about it but I thought even if it is the wrong type I can buy the one that you recommend as well. If Hohner Special 20 Progressive series works well, then I will continue with it :)